# Is it possible backreference to repeated group in perl subsitution regexp pattern

Tags: regex, string, perl, reverse

I ran the script like this:

```
echo "0x4e46436b|0x6669746f|0x74616369|0x416e6f69|0x624f796e|0x7463656a"|perl -pe 's/0x([\da-f]{2}){4}/0x\4\3\2\1/g'
```

and I got this:

```
0x6b|0x6f|0x69|0x69|0x6e|0x6a
```

how to fix the script to get result like this:

```
0x6b43464e|0x6f746966|0x69636174|0x696f6e41|0x6e794f62|0x6a656374
```

Thanks!

---

Alternative: perl -pe's/0x\K([\da-f]{8})/ unpack "H*", pack "V", hex $1 /eg' – ikegami

Thank to ikegami! It's brand new usage of subsitution for me. It works!

Comment: I know I can write the script like this:   perl -pe 's/0x([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})/0x\4\3\2\1/g' .

Comment: Is there any solution backreference to repeated group?

Comment: No, there is no way to reference an unknown amount of captured values of a repeated capturing group, since there is no stack with those values, only the last one is kept in the group memory buffer.

Comment: Alternative: `perl -pe's/0x\K([\da-f]{8})/ unpack "H*", pack "V", hex $1 /eg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of groups that you can refer to from the replacement pattern is limited to the number of capturing groups defined in the pattern. See more details about [repeated capturing groups here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). You have only 1 capturing group in the `0x([\da-f]{2}){4}` pattern, and that means you cannot use a `$2`, or `$3` placeholders in the replacement pattern.

You may use several capturing groups because you have a *fixed* number of repetitions (only four set by the `{4}` quantifier):

```
echo "0x4e46436b|0x6669746f|0x74616369|0x416e6f69|0x624f796e|0x7463656a" | \
  perl -pe 's/0x([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})/0x$4$3$2$1/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3IqqHk)

Note that it is [advised to use `$n` notation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) for placeholders inside the replacement pattern when using perl.